# Should Program class be static?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am getting the following Warning in Visual Studio 2019, after creating a new ASP.NET Core 3 project:

Warning CA1052
Type 'Program' is a static holder type but is neither static nor NotInheritable

```cs
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ...
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            // ...
    }
```

vs

```cs
public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ...
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            // ...
    }
```

Should I add the static modifier? Why / Why not? Pro's and Cons'?

Edit: This is a ASP.NET Core 3 **API**

Comment: Did you read what [the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1052?view=vs-2019) has to say on the topic?

Comment: I did, but Program, as you know, is a special case

Comment: How is Program a special case? It doesn't even need to be called Program. Any class with a static void Main can be an entry point for a starting app

Comment: So, why Microsoft didn't make Program a static class? They should?

Comment: *Any class with a static void Main can be an entry point for a starting app*

Comment: Static class was introduced as part of C# 2.0 https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11857/Introducing-C-2-0-static-classes Whether `Program` class is static or not, when the application runs the right Main function will be called. That warning just indicates that this class can be made static. There is little cons there.

Comment: @CaiusJard I am not talking about Main method, I am talking about Program class

Comment: The error message says "Type 'Program' is.." purely because that's what you've chosen to call it in your app. Rename it to ProgramX and watch the error change. There is nothing special or significant about the word "Program" in relation to this

Answer (score 34):

In more basic terms the message could be imagined to say:

> Your class 'Program' only seems to contain methods that are declared as static and as a result it can not participate in an inheritance hierarchy. Declare it as static (or sealed if you're targeting an ancient version of .net that doesn't support static classes) to more accurately reflect what its design sentiment is

It's a recommendation, to mark your class as static because it only contains static stuff. This will prevent anyone making the mistake of trying to inherit from it and thinking they can then do something useful inheritance-wise with the inherited version

Microsoft don't mark it as static for you because there's nothing special about Program per se; you could put non static methods in it, or your could put your `static void Main` in another class, like Person, that IS instantiable.

```
class Person{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  static void Main(){
    Person p = new Person();
    p.Name = Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

This would work fine; a class does not have to be static to host the application entry point and in this case the class couldn't be static because it has non static members. It can be (and is, in the main) instantiated in the main. It's not called Program; there isn't a class called Program anywhere and this tiny app will still run (doesn't do much..)

In your case, either do as recommended and add a static modifier to your class, because it will make your program that bit more robustly engineered, or add an instance member if you can think of a valid reason for instantiating Program, or ignore the message and carry on with your non static class that contains only static methods - it'll still work